# Postgresql config parameter timezone don't change timezone in data base

Tags: postgresql, timezone

I change parameter timezone and log_timezone in postgresql.conf by this doc:
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-datetime.html

From documenttaion: The TimeZone configuration parameter can be set in the file postgresql.conf

```
timezone = 'Europe/Moscow'
log_timezone = 'Europe/Moscow'
```

File postgresql.conf i could changed in docker.
But parameter timezone don't change in database by this sql:

```
SELECT * FROM pg_settings where name like '%timezone%' or name = 'TimeZone';
```

timezone parameter is 'UTC' now. Why???
And log_timezone changed! What is it?!

My postgresql is in docker.

postgresql version: PostgreSQL 13.1 (Debian 13.1-1.pgdg100+1)
Thanks.

Comment: Did you reload the configuration? (or restart the database cluster, that also works)

Comment: i reload configuration with select pg_reload_conf(); and restart docker container. It don't help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that the parameter `timezone` could (and should!) be overridden in the database session to set the appropriate session time zone. To see if your parameter value is from `postgresql.conf` or was set somewhere else, query `pg_settings`:

```
SELECT setting, source, sourcefile, sourceline
FROM pg_settings
WHERE name = 'TimeZone';
```

Comment: in column source value is 'client'. That is it?)

Comment: That means that your client has overridden the parameter with an explicit `SET`.

Answer (score 0):

Changes in postgresql.conf take effect only if they are there *before* the database loads it - it's read on startup. To re-load them, you'll need to restart or run [`pg_reload_conf()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-admin.html#FUNCTIONS-ADMIN-SIGNAL-TABLE). This one's fine but some settings do require a full restart, which you need to check on case-by-case basis.

Mind that what you're trying to do sets the cluster-wide default - all connections to all databases on this cluster will assume this time zone, but they are all free to [set their own](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/config-setting.html). All defaults take effect at the start of each session, so all ongoing sessions will disregard all changes after that and cannot be forced to change their settings from the outside - they need to either re-connect for changes to apply, or apply them on their own.

`Postgresql.conf` and [`alter system set`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-altersystem.html) affect defaults on cluster, [`alter database set`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-alterdatabase.html) on db, [`alter [role|user] set`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-alterrole.html) on role level. When session starts, it can open by issuing its own [`set`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-set.html) or [`set_config()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-admin.html#FUNCTIONS-ADMIN-SET), which will override all those settings and there's no (built-in) way to revoke anyone's right to `set`.

[Demo at db<>fiddle:](https://dbfiddle.uk/vAujETud)

```
select current_database(),current_user,current_setting('timezone');
```

| current_database | current_user | current_setting |
| --- | --- | --- |
| postgres | postgres | UTC |

This changes the default, without affecting current settings:

```
alter database postgres set timezone='Europe/Moscow';
select current_database(),current_user,current_setting('timezone');
```

| current_database | current_user | current_setting |
| --- | --- | --- |
| postgres | postgres | UTC |

Same: change to role-level default doesn't affect ongoing session(s):

```
alter role current_user set timezone='Europe/Moscow';
select current_database(),current_user,current_setting('timezone');
```

| current_database | current_user | current_setting |
| --- | --- | --- |
| postgres | postgres | UTC |

Only `set` command or [`set_config()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-admin.html#FUNCTIONS-ADMIN-SET) function can affect the session, from the inside.

```
begin;
set local timezone='Europe/Moscow';
select current_database(),current_user,current_setting('timezone');
commit;
select current_database(),current_user,current_setting('timezone');
```

| current_database | current_user | current_setting |
| --- | --- | --- |
| postgres | postgres | Europe/Moscow |

(`set local` and `set_config('name','value',true)` makes the setting go back to what it was before the transaction after it ends)

| current_database | current_user | current_setting |
| --- | --- | --- |
| postgres | postgres | UTC |

`set session` and `set_config('name','value',false)` keeps the setting after the transaction even if it was issued inside it:

```
begin;
set session timezone='Europe/Moscow';
select current_database(),current_user,current_setting('timezone');
commit;
select current_database(),current_user,current_setting('timezone');
```

| current_database | current_user | current_setting |
| --- | --- | --- |
| postgres | postgres | Europe/Moscow |

| current_database | current_user | current_setting |
| --- | --- | --- |
| postgres | postgres | Europe/Moscow |

Comment: Not completely true, it depends on the parameter.

Comment: @FrankHeikens what are you referring to?

Comment: @Zagarek: At least to half of the configuration settings. That's why pg_reload_conf() exists, to reload and activate the new configuration settings. If this could only be done by restarting the server, nobody would have written the code for this SQL function.

Comment: @FrankHeikens Got it, it did sound like I'm suggesting restart is the only way to apply the file-level config - I added an edit, thanks. The idea there was to open with explanation why OP's edits to postgresql.conf didn't immediately take effect but I think the key part they were missing was not how to effectively change the setting (they did try both restarts and reloads, so they did change it), but the multiple levels they get overridden on, on their way from the file (cluster) level, through db, role, session and transaction, and that they have no external control over ongoing sessions.

Answer (score 0):

Tin of course. The config was applied on the server. This is my intellij idea client changing timezone purely for himself. I check

```
   select * from current_timestamp;
```

in psql console and pgadmin. It is normal time with my timezone. Thanks everybody

Comment: All you need is to set the time zone you need in data source settings -> Options -> Time zone (see attached screenshot) https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/DBE-2996/Postgres-Database-console-sets-different-timezone-in-session-that-PGAdmin